# Is it safe to log the value of this in constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, this

I am working on tracing the constructor and its destructed instance and for that I am planning to log the value of "this" in constructor and destructor. I don't know whether it is safe to log value of "this" in constructor. If it is not safe then I wan't to know the scenarios where it will fail ?

Answer (score 8):

If by "logging" you mean "writing out the value as e.g. a hexadecimal address to a log file", it is fine and safe. If not, please clarify.

Objects are not fully constructed until the constructor call is finished. So before that (i.e. from within the constructor) it is not safe to publish `this` to the rest of the program. Because that might result in someone trying to actually use the half-constructed object. This may lead to subtle and hard to find bugs.

Publishing `this` may mean one of the following things:

- passing it as a parameter to an external (non-member) function,
- storing it in a data structure available to other objects,
- (for the sake of completeness: returning it from a function call - which does not apply in this specific case, because you can't return anything from a constructor).

Writing out the address of `this` to a file is thus not publishing it to the rest of your program* so it should be fine.

*<sub>well, unless you do some very arcane things afterwards, like loading back the address from the file in a different thread/process and casting it back to an object pointer... which is already unsafe enough by itself :-)</sub>

Comment: yes I just want to save this value in log file and whenever destructor of that instance called, again I will log this value. I am doing this to identify those instance (this) for which destructor is not getting called. One more thing I am doing while saving the value of this in constructor, I am saving the call stack in log file. With the help of call stack and this, I can easily get to know which call stack instance is not destructed.

Comment: I have asked the same question to my colleagues too, they said its not safe to log value of this in constructor as at that time object was not fully constructed. Please clear my doubt and let me know the scenarios where it will failed

Comment: No no I am not loading this value again in program. I already explained you the scenario for which I am using this. I just want to track the non-destructed instances.

Comment: If you want to verify if some `this` is not destroyed, you're totally okay by saving the this value at DTOR and CTOR. You just have to make sure not to USE it as an object, but just as an integer value. I sometimes do that too to verify that all my objects are correctly destroyed :)

Comment: So, the sceanrio that I am using to track to constructor and destructor by logging this, Is safe and I am logging call stack too in constructor. I think this is good way to track non-destructed sequence in a program and will easily find memory leak too. Thanks peter and Gui13.

Comment: @ShashankJain, I was pretty sure you aren't doing any nastyness like the one I desribe in my footnote. I only added it for completeness, because technically it *is* possible to do, so someone in a nitpicky mood may object to me saying that this is safe - even though 99.99999...% of programmers have never done and will never do such tricks.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you think it is not safe? it is no different to logging the address of any objects in fact so long as those objects are valid.

The long and short of it is that it is safe in the scenarios you are intending to use it for.

Comment: As at that object was not fully constructed. So, I thought its not safe, it may throw garbage ?

Comment: If you reach the constructor stage the object is constructed, it's members may not be depending on how your are initialising your members i.e. initialiser list vs. some initialise() function so your members may have garbage values but the class object will be valid

Comment: So, the sceanrio that I am using to track to constructor and destructor by logging this, Is safe and I am logging call stack too in constructor. I think this is good way to track non-destructed sequence in a program and will easily find memory leak too.

Answer (score 0):

Memory is allocated first, then `this` is set, then the constructor(s) is called. So you're fine to use `this` during the constructor, as it points to the right place - the construction won't change `this`. However if construction fails (throws) the memory will disappear and the value pointed to by `this` will be garbage so you shouldn't store it and use it for anything outside the constructor until you know the construction will succeed.